# When I use an PaintComponent to my JFrame, I have to resize my window to get it to show up unless I use pack. How can I remedy this?

Tags: java, swing

I am creating a Blackjack game, and I'm trying to get cards to show up on top of the table image when the hit button is hit. However, they keep showing up to the side of the table image, and only either show up a. when I use the pack() method in the ActionListener, or if I don't use pack(), when I resize the window.

My Code:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class BlackjackTable3 extends JFrame {


  JButton stayButton = new JButton("STAY");
  JButton hitButton = new JButton("HIT");
  JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

  public BlackjackTable3() {
    this.setTitle("Blackjack Test Table");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel tablePanel = new JPanel();
    ImageIcon pic = new ImageIcon("blackjackTableCanvas.jpg");
    mainPanel.add(new JLabel(pic), BorderLayout.NORTH);




    this.add(mainPanel);
    this.setSize(1600,1600);
    this.setVisible(true);

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    ActionListener pressChoice = new DecisionListener();
    hitButton.addActionListener(pressChoice);
    stayButton.addActionListener(pressChoice);

    buttonPanel.setSize(300,150);
    buttonPanel.add(hitButton,BorderLayout.WEST);
   buttonPanel.add(stayButton,BorderLayout.EAST);
    buttonPanel.setVisible(true);
    this.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

  }



  class DecisionListener implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){
      //code for hit/stay to go here

      if(a.getSource() == hitButton){
        System.out.println("YOU CHOSE HIT!");
        CardRender2 c = new CardRender2(new Card());

        mainPanel.add(c, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
      }
      else if(a.getSource() == stayButton){
        System.out.println("YOU CHOSE STAY!");
      }

    }
  }



  public static void main(String[] args){
    BlackjackTable3 b = new BlackjackTable3();

  }

}
```

My CardRender2 code:

```
public class CardRender2 extends JComponent{ 
public CardRender2(Card card) {
  this.val = card.value.face;
    this.suit = card.suit.toString();
    String filename = this.fetchCardFileLabel();
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File("card deck\\" + filename + ".png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JLabel j = new JLabel();
    j.add(this);

}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    super.paintComponent(g2);
    g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

}
...}
```

I tried using repaint(), and I can't use paint bc I get a compiler error. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Take `this.setVisible(true);` and make it the last thing you call after you've established the UI - this is a relatively common question. Swing is lazy with it's updates, so if you want to dynamically update the UI after it's realized on the screen, you will need to call `revalidate` and `repaint` to trigger a layout and paint pass

Comment: where would I add those methods (revalidate and repaint)? I tried repaint in DecisionListener, nothing happens. I just did revalidate, and its better than pack, but I want those cards appearing on the table, not next to it.

Comment: `revalidate` and `repaint` need to be made on the container which was changed, that would, presumably be, the frame's `contentPane` - *" but I want those cards appearing on the table, not next to it"* - would be an issue with the layout manager

Comment: Without more information, I'd either consider a `CardLayout` or, more likely, simply update the existing `JLabel` with the new image, instead of creating a new instance of `CardRender2` each time.  You also don't need to paint the image, as the label will do that anyway so it's kind of redundant

Comment: No need for a custom component to do the painting.  Just use a JLabel to display the image.

Comment: @camickr I tried that, and posted about it, got shut down. That being said, how can I place these cards OVER, ON TOP OF, the table image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can I place these cards OVER, ON TOP OF, the table image?

You need a hierarchy of components something like:

- JFrame

  - background component with image

    - card component with image

One way is to use labels to contain your images:

```
JLabel card = new JLabel(...);
JLabel background = new JLabel(...);
background.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );
background.add( card );
frame.add(background, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

This will only work if the background image is bigger than your card component.